# Подскажите как сделать изменения титла UIBarButtonItem правой кнопки?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, navigationcontroller

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать чтоб у `UIBarButtonItem` изменялось название кнопки? Если это страница профиля пользователя, т.е. пользователь зарегистрированный то показывало название "Изменить" а если новый пользователь и без регистрации то название было "Регистрация". Пример кода где скрывается таблица и метод срабатывает. А тут застрял, очень буду благодарен за помощь и пример.

```
let rightButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(newTitleBar(_:)))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonItem

@IBOutlet weak var barButtonString: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func newTitleBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let user = PFUser.current()

    if (user?.isAuthenticated)! {
        sender.title = "Изменить"
    } else {
        sender.title = "Зарегится"
    } 
}
```

Вот так сделал `tableview` и таблица скрывается.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let user = PFUser.current()
    if (user?.isAuthenticated)!  {
        self.tableView.isHidden = true     
    } else  if (user?.isNew)! {
        self.tableView.isHidden = false                    
    }
}
```

Это  мои переходы к контроллерам.

```
@objc func segueEdit() {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showUser", sender: self)
}

@objc func segueReg(){
    func presentController() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Зарегистрироваться"
        let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "registration") as! RegistarationController

        self.present(VC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: В segueReg опечатки нет? А то у Вас там функция объявлена, и при этом она не вызывается.

Comment: Роман я сделать действие .Когда захожу без авторизации чтоб титле UIBarButtonItem правого показывало мне титле "Зарегистрироваться" а  если юзер авторизовался.ТО показывало титле Изменить .Переходы то все нормально будет идти.Я не могу добиться этого метода.

Comment: Пробовали вызывать в `newTitleBar ` вот такое: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = (user?.isAuthenticated)! ? "Изменить" : "Зарегится"`?

Comment: Нет, а полностью можете пример показать